# Who do Style is not properly aligned in DHTMLX scheduler recurring events in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, alignment, dhtmlx-scheduler

I am using DHTMLX scheduler in MVC. I am adding recurring events in DHTMLX scheduler. While adding recurring events, style is not properly aligned in the scheduler. Is there any important file am missing for `dhtmlxscheduler_recurring`?